# ModelChoiceField labels are incorrect

Tags: django, django-forms

Not sure how to update the labels on a ModelChoiceField

Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    categoryText = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parentCat = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
```

Form:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.Form):
    category  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

Right now when I display the form, I get "Category Object" as the lable of the drop down.  I like to change the lables to what is stored in categoryText.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryText = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parentCat = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.categoryText
```

The unicode method is used internally by Django when it want's to print a human-friendly version of the particular model object/table row (in the admin, or as a form label for example). You should write a unicode method for every model you create.

[Here is django's entry about the unicode function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__)

Comment: It worked - thanks
Just now sure why it worked.  
could I have done it with __init__ also?

Comment: `__unicode__` is a method called by Django (and Python in general) to generate a string representation of an instance of a class. In this case it simply returns the value of its `categoryText` field.

Comment: exactly, so it doesn't make sense to try do it with init. If your question is answered, accept the answer by clicking the green arrow beside the votes on the left